# How to create a two column CSS Grid and make items fit-content

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, css-grid

I have this layout that I am trying to build:

[image: Two column layout with fit-content items.]

I am struggling to figure out how I can use `display: flex` or `display: grid` to achieve the result.

The criteria here is:

- There are only two items per row
- The items must only be the width of their content
- They should be centered to the container.

I have tried with `display: grid` but the items always span the width of the grid.

I tried the following

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid > * {
  width: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="grid">
    <li>Hello World</li>
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
    <li>Dolor Set Amigo</li>
    <li>Some other placeholder</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you able to alter the HTML?

Comment: @0stone0 yes I can

Answer (score 1):

A solution which forces line breaks is to make an empty list item which spans the full width of the parent using `flex basis`.

```css
.break {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hello Wd</li>
  <li>Helloaaa World</li>
  <li class="break" />
  <li>Helor World Worldld</li>
  <li>Hello WorldWorldWorldWorld</li>
  <li class="break" />
  <li>HelorWorldWorldld</li>
  <li>Hello World</li>
  <li class="break" />
  <li>Helorld</li>
  <li>Hello WorldWorldWorldWorldWorld</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible with your current HTML setup.

Here an example which uses an additional `div` for each row holding 2 items.

Hope this helps / fits your needs

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid red;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
}

.row > em:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

em {
    padding: 2px 5px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">    
        <em>Hello World</em>
        <em>Foo</em>
    </div>
    <div class="row">    
        <em>Bar</em>
        <em>Lorem ipsum</em>
    </div>
    <div class="row">    
        <em>Dolor Set Amigo</em>
        <em>Some other placeholder</em>
    </div>
</div>
```